# Console text red at boot (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, colors, console

When CentOS 7 is booting, the text becomes red. This happens through IPMI and a direct connected VGA screen. The server seems to be OK, but I would like to know why all console text is red.

The OS is clean installed.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Like I said this also happens on IPMI. It really is red and after a while it goes white

Comment: VGA cable/connector error, missing one colour.

Comment: @IporSircer As said, it's also red on IPMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Looks like it has to do with the kernel's support for ASpeed's video adapter (used on Supermicro and possibly other motherboards).  I found that moving from kernel-3.10.0-862 to kernel-3.10.0-957.1.3 fixed the problem.

The ast driver relied on the kernel to call a setup routine and that setup routine was removed prior to 3.10.0-862 but the ast fix wasn't applied.  The routine is called when DPMS is set so blanking then unblanking the screen should set the color to normal.

removal: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b8e2b0199cc377617dc238f5106352c06dcd3fa2
ast fix: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/24b8ef699e8221d2b7f813adaab13eec053e1507